# Change of index in for loop Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a loop like this :

```
 for i = 1:3
        M = 1
        for M = M:12
                while (S(M) == i)
                    M = M+1
                end
        end
    end
```

Now for the new incremented value of M in while loop the 'for' loop is not working for this new value. 
Any solutions?

Comment: You can't have `M` both being the loop index and the lower bound of the loop, it doesn't make sense. It's also bad practice to change the index of the loop within the loop body. Nothing in your code makes sense. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended functionality is, can you please clarify. M will always loop over the values given in the for loop even if you change M inside that loop. As you reset M each iteration you are just doing the same thing 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't make any sense!

You should start to use different names for your parameters,

And note that:

```
for index = values
   program statements
      :
end
```

> Avoid assigning a value to the index variable within the body of a loop. The for statement overrides any changes made to the index within the loop.

For the second loop `for M = M : 12` is the same as `for M = 1 : 12`.

MATLAB takes the *index* values at their first definition, for example,

```
a = [1 2];
for i = a
   disp(i);
   a = [1 2 3];
end
```

You will see that `i` won't accept the value `3` because at the first use of `for`, `i` is set over `[1 2]`.